# <f:ajax> contains an unknown id when switching from PrimeFaces to jsf/html

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, facelets

this is my 1st question here :)

My code is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<f:view xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    >

    <h:head />

    <h:body>
        <h:form id="filterForm">
            <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="main.css" />
            <div id="filterPane">
                <h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty filters.categories}">
                    <div class="filter">
                        <div class="filterCategories" style="width: 100%;">
                            <h4>Kategorien</h4>
                            <p />
                            <h:selectManyCheckbox layout="pageDirection"
                                value="#{filters.selectedCategories}"
                                valueChangeListener="#{filters.categoryValueChanged}">
                                <f:selectItems value="#{filters.categories}" var="category"
                                    itemLabel="#{category.displayName} (#{category.count})"
                                    itemValue="#{category.name}" />
                                <f:ajax render="@form" />
                            </h:selectManyCheckbox>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </div>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>

</f:view>
```

I get the same error as some others before me here @stackoverflow - but none of the suggested solutions worked for me.:

```
<f:ajax> contains an unknown id 'A5539:filterForm:j_idt9' - cannot locate it in the context of the component j_idt9
```

Before my switch from `<p:selectManyCheckbox` to `<h:selectManyCheckbox` the code was working fine.

We need to change to `<h:selectedManyCheckbox`, because the PrimeFaces variant is not selectable for a non-JavaScript user. I need the form `<h:form id="filterForm">` to be re-rendered as a consequence of my AJaX request via the `<f:ajax>` element.

Beside the initial `<f:ajax render="@form" />` I unsuccessfully tried to reference the `<h:form id="filterForm">` element with the following variants:

```
<f:ajax render=":filterForm" />
<f:ajax render=":#{component.parent.parent}" />
```

I also tried some more stupid ones.

Any hint, anybody!? :)

Comment: Is that an include file or tag file or something? I don't see component with ID `A5539` anywhere. If it is, then the syntax is really strange. The `<f:view>`, `<h:head>` and `<h:body>` doesn't belong in an include file / tag file.

Comment: If you are migrating `selectManyCheckbox` from PrimeFaces to standard JSF element, how users with JavaScript disabled in their browser will use AJAX requests?

Comment: @BalusC It is not used as an include file.What do you mean by "strange syntax"?

Comment: @BalusC Thx for your comment. Just learned about the 5min edit timeout. Do you know how these IDs are generated? Do you mean I should have the `id="A5539"` assigned to some element in my code in order to get this error?

Comment: @partlov
I want to offer a plain old form button to submit via POST for the JS diabled users and also include some JS to hide this button for the JS enabled users.